# ordering mysql table for the max of two variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, max

hope someone can help me with this issue.

I have a table with two columns, and i want to select items from that table and order them depending on which of these two values is higher.

lets say i have columns 'x' and 'y' and i have these entries:

```
     x ;  y
1.- 10 ; 12
2.-  5 ; 10
3.- 11 ; 20
```

i want the response to be ordered: 3, 1, 2

i know this wont help, since it has no sence in the mysql, but is a representation of my idea

```
$query = (mysql_query("SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY MAX(x, y)"));
```

i dont want to create a new variable in the table for this query.

Any idea? thanks a lot

Comment: your sample data doesn't match your expected sort order

Comment: Try to use IF(expr1,expr2,expr3) control flow function.

Comment: As I understand the question, your example should return 3, 2, 1

Comment: sry, typing mistake... i just edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to sort it after x or y, depending which is higher?

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY GREATEST(x, y)
```

But in your case this is 3, 2, 1 because 15(y) is higher than -5(x) and also higher than the greatest in row 1. So I am a bit confused.

---

Supporting NULLs and correct order:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(x, 0), COALESCE(y, 0)) DESC
```

If you need other value as default than `0` just replace it.

Comment: As you fixed your typo the result should be 3, 1, 2 now.

Comment: @Zollway: `ORDER BY GREATEST(x, y) DESC`

Comment: this method does not work when i have a null on soem of the colums... it works kind of unpredictable. Anyways ill just change the null values for 0. Works perfect, thanks

Comment: @Dan: You hadn't mentioned you had `NULL`s in the columns.

Comment: your correct, my bad. Anyways is great idea since its quite easy to change nulls for 0 and it will work

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
  * 
from 
  products
order by
  Case when x>y then x else y end DESC
```

Comment: I'm a SQLServer dev and we don't have a `Greatest()` but the case statement works just as well

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY GREATEST(x,y) DESC
       , LEAST(x,y) DESC
```

The second part of the ordering (LEAST) is to put a row with `(12,20)` before a row with `(10,20)`.

---

Since the two fields can have `NULL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY GREATEST( COALESCE(x,0), COALESCE(y,0) ) DESC
       , LEAST(    COALESCE(x,0), COALESCE(y,0) ) DESC ;
```